# Replace specific part of src attribute into an iframe element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, blogger

Is there any way to replace specific part of `src` attribute into an `iframe` element?

I have this iframe from a google blog I am working on...

```
<iframe allowtransparency='true' id='reactions-iframe' class='reactions-iframe' expr:src='data:post.reactionsUrl'  frameborder='0' name='reactions' scrolling='no'/>
```

When blog loads the `src` attribute becomes like this...

```
src="https://www.blogger.com/blog-post-reactions.g?options=%5BLike,+Dislike%5D&textColor=%23000000#http://www.blog-name.com/post-name.html"
```

So, when blog loads I want to replace the part `textColor=%23000000#` to `textColor=%23ffffff#` for example. How can I do that using javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `onLoad` event to your iframe:

```
<iframe allowtransparency='true' id='reactions-iframe' class='reactions-iframe' expr:src='data:post.reactionsUrl'  frameborder='0' name='reactions' scrolling='no' onLoad='changeSrc();'/>
```

And in the `changeSrc()` function execute this code to change the src value:

```
function changeSrc() {

    const frame = document.getElementById('reactions-iframe');

    frame.src = frame.src.replace('textColor=%23000000#', 'textColor=%23ffffff#');

}
```